# How to extract the username and password from a jenkins "username with password" parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job.  It takes several parameters, one of which is a "Username with password" parameter, which is set to a "service account" that I've had provisioned.

This is used in the "StashNotifier" to notify BitBucket of the results of a build.

I now have to add some "scp/ssh" steps to the job, and I'd like to use the same service account principal and credentials.  I could manually add two parameters, redundant copies of the username and password of the service account parameter, but I would really like to just extract the pieces from the existing "Username and password" parameter.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you need the user name and password reachable in the Jenkinsfile? Does this help - getRemoteUrlWithCredentials(credentialsId) { withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: credentialsId, usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) { def scmUrl = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl() scmUrl = scmUrl.substring(scmUrl.indexOf("github.com")) return "https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@${scmUrl}" } }

Comment: Yes, I need to reference them from the Jenkinsfile (wasn't that obvious?). What you've provided here seems like it comes close.

Comment: OK. Just remove the git parts and change the variable names to your likings

Answer (score 4):

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: credentialsId, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) { 
    // use USERNAME and PASSWORD as envs - ${USERNAME}
    // credentialId is the credential id from Credentials tab 
}
```

Comment: And after looking at this some more, I don't see how I can use this, as neither scp or ssh take password parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you are using ssh/scp the [ssh-agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/) is what you want. (And usually you also want public key authentication instead of the password, but that is another story)

```
node {
    sshagent (credentials: ['your-credential-id']) {
        sh 'ssh blaa blaa'
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked into sshagent, and I'd prefer to use a "native" solution like this, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to use it from a pipeline job. I'll try this, but I wish I could find this documented somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what syntax is required to specify the credentials id.  I have a "Username and password" parameter that's stored in a variable. Let's call it "foo". What should I specify here?

Comment: I'm guessing it's possible "your-credential-id" is supposed to be the UUID of the credential I see in "Manage Jenkins"->"Credentials". This still isn't working.  I'll update the base note with more info.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @jil it would make things a lot easier if you'd use ssh keys for the authentication at your SSH server - assuming your jenkins server is running on a linux / unix machine. You can add the keys to the system user `jenkins` which runs Jenkins and copy it to the machine to which you want to connect for your scp / ssh steps. Afterwards you can directly use any ssh / scp command without providing a password.

> There are some **security considerations** though: adding the SSH key to the `jenkins` user enables every job on the Jenkins server to access your SSH server.

If this is not a problem for you - this is a [good article on how to use ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).